# Sort an accordion-table (jquery)

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm looking for an accordion table which can be sorted and paged.  I couldn't find any sort/page plugin which would allow my table to have an accordion effect.

In order to get the accordion effect, and to group each row for manipulation, I used multiple tbody tags.

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Zulu</td>
      <td>Raleigh</td>
      <td>North Carolina</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse">
      <td colspan="4">...hidden panel...</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Yankee</td>
      <td>Detroit</td>
      <td>Michigan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse">
      <td colspan="4">...hidden panel...</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

```
$('.jAccordionTable').each(accordionTable);

function accordionTable(i,elem) {
    var table = $(elem);
    var rows = table.find('tbody');

    //accordion on tbody > tr
    rows.find('tr:first').addClass('table-acc-header');
    rows.find('tr:last').addClass('table-acc-body');    
    $('.table-acc-header').click(function() {
        table.find('.table-acc-body').addClass('collapse');
        $(this).next('.table-acc-body').removeClass('collapse');
    });

    //header sort
    var th_index = 0;

    table.find('th').click(function() {
        var th_index = $(this).index();
        table.find('tbody').each(mapTDs)
        function mapTDs(i,elem) {
            var tds = $(elem).find('td').eq(th_index).map(function() {
                $(this).parents('tbody').data( "sort", $(this).text() );
                return $(this).text();
            })
            console.log(tds);
        }

        rows.sort(function(a,b){
            var an = a.getAttribute('data-sort'),
                bn = b.getAttribute('data-sort');

            if(an > bn) {
                return 1;
            }
            if(an < bn) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        rows.detach().appendTo(table);
    });
}
```

In this fiddle, I wrote the collapsing of the hidden panels, but my attempts at "sort" aren't working.  **http://jsfiddle.net/s5u1p4g7/1/**

Can anyone point me to a plugin for paging/sorting a table, which I might alter to fit this html structure?  All the ones that I tried are based on TR, not on TBODY, and my attempts to alter them failed.  Or help me fix this "sort"?

Thanks!

...

**Edit for expanded solution with asc/desc and css:**
http://jsbin.com/hexovo/1/edit

Comment: `var th_index = $(this).index();` `th_index` is already defined. There's no need to use `var` again. If you want you can use a shorthand for your `sort` function, it can be simply `return an > bn ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pepoj/1/edit)**

You were on the right track, I Basically made few changes in selectors, added a better sort logic and fixed the `data-*` attribute assignments (using `.attr()`), I've slightly modified your Selectors and variables. Take a look at the changes I did to `mapTDs` function and other. Hope you'll spot the differences.
 (If you have questions feel free to ask!)

```
function accordionTable(i,elem) {
  var table = $(elem),
      tbody = table.find('tbody'),
      th_index = 0,
      th_sortType = "string";

  //accordion on tbody > tr
  tbody.find('tr:first').addClass('table-acc-header');
  tbody.find('tr:last').addClass('table-acc-body');  
  $('.table-acc-header').click(function() {
    table.find('.table-acc-body').addClass('collapse');
    $(this).next('.table-acc-body').removeClass('collapse');
  });

  function mapTDs(i, elem){
    var txt = $("td", elem).eq(th_index).text();
    $(elem).attr("data-sortval", txt);
  }
  function sortAsc(a, b){
    var aData = $(a).attr("data-sortval"),
        bData = $(b).attr("data-sortval");
    if(th_sortType==="int"){ 
      return +bData < +aData ? 1 : -1; // Integer
    }else{   
      return  bData <  aData ? 1 : -1; // String or else
    }
  }

  //header sort
  table.on("click", "th", function() {
    th_sortType = $(this).data('sort');
    th_index = $(this).index();
    tbody = table.find('tbody').each(mapTDs);
    tbody.sort(sortAsc).detach().appendTo(table);
  });
}

$('.jAccordionTable').each(accordionTable);
```

P.S: `mapTDs` is a bit misleading here, we're actually not mapping `TD` elements, but rather getting every **same indexed TD** element's text, and assigning that text to the `.closest()` TBODY element --> into it's `data-sortval` attribute. Once that's done the sort function is run over those attributes reordering the DBODYes in TABLE.

Comment: Nicely done, Roko. Do you think that this script will need edits for the case of very large tables?

Comment: @JenniferMichelle I don't think so. The only downside of it is that index might not work in the case you decide to use colspan attributes for larger cells. In that case yes, you should than read the cell colspan value and account it to the index var.