# Sorting Accordion Table of Accordion Tables - Sorttable?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, accordion, sorttable.js

I am trying to sort an accordion table with sortable accordion tables inside!!! I really like how this layout looks but it has really been a challenge to figure out how to sort it.

I've tried working with this code: [Sortable Accordion Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348441/sort-an-accordion-table-jquery)
but this sorts EVERY `<tbody>` in the table, including the sub-pieces.

I would really like to use sorttable: [JQuery Sorttable](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)
This code is smooth and works great! But it does a similar thing where it sorts ALL `<tr>` in that table, not just the "unhidden ones", but it doesn't sort past that table level.

Here is a link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/LucyTurtle/pen/opGjPE) to see a general layout of my table. Or for a very simple version:

```
<table class="fold-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view">
      <td>Company Name</td>
      <td class="pcs">457</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <table class="fold-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="view">
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td class="pcs">457</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fold">
                <td colspan="7">
                  <div class="fold-content">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Company name</th>
                          <th>Customer no</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13245</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13288</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td class="pcs">457</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fold">
                <td colspan="7">
                  <div class="fold-content">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Company name</th>
                          <th>Customer no</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13245</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13288</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      <td>Company Name</td>
      <td class="pcs">457</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <table class="fold-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="view">
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td class="pcs">457</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fold">
                <td colspan="7">
                  <div class="fold-content">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Company name</th>
                          <th>Customer no</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13245</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13288</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td class="pcs">457</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fold">
                <td colspan="7">
                  <div class="fold-content">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Company name</th>
                          <th>Customer no</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13245</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Sony</td>
                          <td>13288</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Looking for ideas of how to refine these sorts to make then only sort one level of my table at a time.

Comment: You really need to provide more info or show us what you've done so far with your sorting... At this point you're asking us to do all the work for you.

Comment: I have provided both of the sources I am trying to use. I don't need one to be written for me just ideas on how to break out the data or how to format the table to allow for sorting of just one level of the table at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would just use DataTables with nested tables - should work basically out of the box.

Here is a fiddle that does exactly what you want to do with an added bonus of also including a "search" box by default: 
http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/zz3cH/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p>
    This is an example of how you can use Datatables to setup a master/detail relationship and nest details views which can be completely different tables.         
</p>
 <br />    
<h4>Starcraft 2 Progamers | 2014</h4>
<table id="exampleTable">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Race</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div style="display:none">    
    <table id="detailsTable">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Server</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```